# How to Make a Large 々 With the Keyboard

Tags: symbols

I have only seen the sub character `々` used before. Now I am encountering the full size character, but cannot figure out how to enter it into a keyboard.

Also, I know `々` is a repetition marker. Is there any specific use that the larger version serves?

**Example**

日本は、世界の国？の中で。。。

[image]

Comment: Input のま and convert it. Or you're talking about specific fonts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there is no other way to answer your question than:

There is only one 々 character; any differences you are seeing are variation in typefaces/handwriting.

Fonts can vary quite a bit in their proportions, and 々 is technically a symbol and not a kanji (as far as I'm aware), so that's further reason why typeface designers might treat it differently (from each other and from kanji) and give it special sizing.

Four fonts, different sizing:

[image: 国々 in four typefaces]